# Good practice to do common authorization in a custom controller factory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controllers share a client id. Route:

```
clients/{clientId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Sample URLs:

```
clients/1/orders/details/1
clients/2/children/index
clients/2/cars/create
```

You need proper authorization for a client. I don't want to do the same client authorization in every controller. I came up with the idea to do the autorization in a custom controller factory like this:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;

    public CustomControllerFactory(IAuthService authService)
    {
        _authService = authService;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var doAuth = requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("clientId");
        if (doAuth)
        {
            var principal = requestContext.HttpContext.User;
            var clientId = long.Parse(
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["clientId"].ToString());
            var authorized = _authService.Client(principal, clientId);
            if (!authorized)
            {
                return new AuthController();
            }                
        }
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

Do you consider this a good practice or not? Why?

Comment: Why not use a IFilterProvider or the reguler authorization attributes? Either way, I'd use a custom FilterProvider for this instead of a  custom controller factory.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't consider this as a good practice. A custom [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) seems far more adapted to handle authorization rather than a controller factory.

Answer (score 1):

We have already used below concept to check authorization;

Step 1:Need to create 3 different tables and enter appropriate data;

A. Table: Actions

ID:int,PK
Controller:varchar(100)
Action:varchar(100)
HttpMethod:varchar(10)

B. Table: Permission

Id: int,PK
Name: varchar(100)

C. Table: Permission_Action

Id:int,PK
PermissionId:int, FK
ActionId:int, FK

Step 2: Create an ApplicationController that will be inherited from "Controler" class and all other controller should be inherited from "ApplicationController" instead of "Controller".

```
//Declaration of ApplicationController
public class ApplicationController : Controller
//Declaration of Other controller
public class OtherController : ApplicationController
```

Step 3: For persistance, fetch all the controller and actions for a current user after authentication. Insted we can also fire SQL query every time.

Step 4: In "OnActionExecuting" method you will have information about controller and action of the current request. Looked into controller action list, fetched in Step 3, to find out the current controller and action.

```
 string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;
 string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
 string httpMethod = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToLowerInvariant();
```

Step 5: If found then user has right to proceed with an action otherwise return predefined "SecurityResult"

Example:

*NOTE:* actions related to "Authorization" should be assigned at the time of creating users. This part is excluded in this example;

A. Action table data:

{1,"Employee","Detail","get"},{2,"Employee","Create","get"},{3,"Employee","Create","post"},{4,"Employee","Delete","post"}

B. Permission table data:

{1, "View Employee Detail"},{2, "Create Employee Detail"},{3, "Delete Employee Detail"}

C. Permission_Action table data:

{1, 1, 1},{1, 2, 2},{1, 2, 3},{1, 3, 4}

D. Now user "vrluckyin" has only permission for viewing data and creating employee.

*"Delete" action from "Employee" has not been assigned.*

After authorization, if "vrluckyin" user tries to call "delete" action of "Employee" controller then system will return security view instead of delete view.

- No need to write [Authorize] attribute on every action.
- We can add/remove/update user rights easily. Only Database changes!!!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is the absolutely best practice when your application has a very strong multi-tenancy or user-ownership model.

`[Authorize]` attributes, even on the class level, are just clutter if you are decorating the majority of your application with them.  `[Authorize]` attributes can also be forgotten.  Your technique will always work.